# Difference between web driver and web driver backend Selenium and PhantomJs

Tags: java, selenium

i run in PhantomJs code generated from Selenium. With Selenium IDE i can export java code in 2 mode: Java | Web Driver or Java | Web Driver Backend, but how i better?

I ask that because some code exporting with Java | Web Driver not working with PhantomJsDriver but same code exporting with Java | Web Driver Backend work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebDriverBackedSelenium` is provided for backwards compatibility with Selenium 1.0 which is not maintained anymore. So if you have option, you should really be using `WebDriver`, i.e. Selenium 2.0. As of this edit `WebDriver` is on it's way to become a w3c standard. You can find the draft [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/). For those who care about differences between Selenium 1.0 and Selenium 2.0 (WebDriver), here is a high level one,

Selenium 1.0 - is a pure Javascript application. It injects a javascript automation library  into the browser and provides you an API to interact with the browser

Selenium 2.0 - uses browsers native API and therefore simulates users browser interactions better.

In general using IDE is good for initial learning, however I would suggest to write your test code by hand and not by relying on IDE. Selectors generated from IDE are brittle and not readable in my experience. They make your tests brittle. If you want to maintain your tests in long run, you should treat your test code as application code.

As for your issue, have you tried running your WebDriver code on any other browser using say FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver?  A code snippet would help identify the issue better.

Comment: i need a headless browser so i must use PhantomJs..but some code generated with Java | WebDriver not work.. so i think i must use both

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to use any other browser. I wanted to check if the same code runs against any other browser. That would explain some missing configuration on phantomjs side.